# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: Unzip file on HPC Cloud Server

Tags: python, zip, extract, torch, unzip

I am unzip file of 35.8 GB and have a `1.7 TB` space in my Virtual machine to extract zip file. Also, I already give all security permission to execute it but still stuck on `no space left`

Directory is `/home2/coremax` and you can see `10.100.201.21:/cloudhome/coremax 2097152000 692367040 1404784960  34% /home2/coremax` there are lots of space. I am searching on Google but this issue but did not find a solution

[image]

**RAM utilization**

[image]

**Traceback**

```
/home2/coremax/Documents/ocr_dataset/datasets/SynthText/SynthText
Unpacking SynthText:  33%|███▎      | 252421/772875 [2:13:24<4:35:03, 31.54it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/coremax/Documents/doctr/references/recognition/original_pytorch_train.py", line 521, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/home2/coremax/Documents/doctr/references/recognition/original_pytorch_train.py", line 324, in main
    synth_train = SynthText(
  File "/home2/coremax/Documents/doctr/doctr/datasets/synthtext.py", line 114, in __init__
    tmp_img.save(os.path.join(reco_folder_path, f"{reco_images_counter}.png"))
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/envs/doctr_hpc/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2350, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/home2/coremax/Documents/ocr_dataset/datasets/SynthText/SynthText/SynthText_recognition_train/2097151.png'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on Virtual Sever (HPC Cloud) located in a different area so I can connect with a web address.

Firstly, I transfer my `40GB` `zip` file to the HPC Server where I have almost `1.5TB` of space, still, I cannot extract the .zip file and got an error message `"No Space Left"`. I have also checked `inodes`, process,es and everything is ok

FYI: My HPC root directory is only `100GB` so I cannot copy the dataset into the root directory

**Task 1:** Give all permission to .zip file and extract it **(Didn't Work)**

**Task 2:** My trash bin has been highly occupied, It takes 10 hours to empty it. Then, I extracted it again **(Didn't Work)**

**Solution:** The type of hard disk in HPC Sever is `NFS` - based does not allow the extraction of large zip files so I made a virtual partition in my `1.5TB` hard disk with `ext4` format and mount it with root. Afterward, I extracted the `.zip` file and it works for me.